# XSD can't get external namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, namespaces

I want to generate C# code, based on XSD file, but there is problem with
namspaces in schema, VS and xsd.exe shows warnings at all types defined in one particular namespace. I thought that it might be actually wrong but I opened XSD file in XSD Diagram (a program for opening such files) and it shows each type properly even though they are in that one namespace.

Problematic namespace is ***xmlns:curr="http://www.currenda.pl/epu"***

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:curr="http://www.currenda.pl/epu" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.currenda.pl/epu" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0" xml:lang="pl">
  <xsd:element name="Pozwy">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Paczka pozwów w elektronicznym postępowaniu upominawczym</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="PozewEPU" type="curr:PozewEPU" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="OznaczeniePaczki" type="curr:typNazwa60" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>Oznaczenie paczki nadawane przez powoda masowego używane jako kryterium wyszukiwania i rozliczania opłat</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name="PozewEPU">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Pozew inicjujący sprawę w elektronicznym postępowaniu upominawczym</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Oswiadczenie" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>Przyjmuje wartości tak/nie</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="Adresat" type="curr:typAdresat" />
      <xsd:element name="SadWlasciwy" type="curr:typAdresat" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="OsobaSkladajaca" type="curr:typSkladajacy" />
      <xsd:element name="ListaPowodow" type="curr:typListaPowodow" />
      <xsd:element name="ListaPozwanych" type="curr:typListaPozwanych" />
      <xsd:element name="SprawaWgPowoda" minOccurs="0" type="curr:typNazwa60">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>Sygnatura / oznaczenie sprawy nadane przez powoda </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="WartoscSporu" type="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>Suma wartości roszczeń zdefiniowanych na liście roszczeń wyrażona w PLN</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="OplataSadowa" type="curr:typOplata" />
      <xsd:element name="KosztyZastepstwa" type="curr:typKoszty" />
      <xsd:element name="InneKoszty" type="curr:typKoszty" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="RachunekDoZwrotuOplat" type="curr:typRachunekDoZwrotuOplat" >
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>Element dla numeru oraz nazwy właściciela rachunku do zwrotu opłat sądowych</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="ListaRoszczen" type="curr:typLista" />
      <xsd:element name="ListaDowodow" type="curr:typListaDowodow" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="InneRoszczenia" type="curr:typTekstowy" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="Uzasadnienie" type="curr:typTekstowy" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="ID" type="xsd:unsignedLong" use="required">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Unikalny w ramach paczki numer ID pozwu </xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="version" type="curr:typNazwa10" use="required" fixed="1.0">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Oznaczenie wersji formatu </xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="dataZlozenia" type="curr:typData" use="required" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

[image: Screen from xsd.exe]

In errors it is said: Type [...] was not declared

I will appreciate any help
Thanks in advance

EDIT: Part of xsd with data types (it's too big to pase it whole

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:curr="http://www.e-sad.gov.pl/epu" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.e-sad.gov.pl/epu" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.0" xml:lang="pl">
  <xsd:simpleType name="typNIP">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Numer NIP</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:pattern value="([1-9]((\d[1-9])|([1-9]\d))\d{7})|(^$)" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="typPESEL">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Definicja numeru PESEL</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{11}" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="typKRS">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Definicja KRS </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{10}" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: Your XSD indeed does not define a `typNazwa10` type, a `typData` type, or any types at all besides `PozewEPU`. Are they defined in some other file?

Comment: Actually I'm new to xml so I thought that they were declared in that namespace, but I see now that I have also xsd with those types, how am I supposed to attach it?

Comment: I believe you can do so by adding `<xsd:import namespace="http://www.currenda.pl/epu" schemaLocation="theOtherFileNameGoesHere.xsd" />` to the XSD above.

Comment: Unfortunately when I add this line I get 3 warnings:
"The namespace attribute for the import can not match the actual value of the targetNamespace element of the <schema> element."

"Cannot recognise schemaLocation attribute"

And one strange warning about System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that that was the namespace of this `xsd` as well. How about: `<xsd:include schemaLocation="theOtherFileNameGoesHere.xsd" />`

Comment: @JLRishe: Make your `xsd:include` comment an answer so it can be upvoted and (probably) accepted.  Thanks.  pablocity: Your XSD itself, before giving to `xsd.exe`, has to be correct, which includes all referenced types being defined.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I got seriously stucked, I changed this line to include, and in schemaLocation I wrote path to this xsd file with types, but I have still warnings:
1.The attached "TypyDanych.xsd" schema was not recognized
2.Cannot resolve schemaLocation attribute
3.System.Security.Permissions.FileIoPermission permission request failed

I tried dozen approaches, was changing path to URI to absolute path to relative path and still nothing
I edited post to show that file with data types

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because your XSD uses types that are defined elsewhere. xsd.exe needs all the definitions in order to work. Based on what you've said in the comments, it sounds like you need to include another file by referencing it like this in the main file:

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="theOtherFileNameGoesHere.xsd" />
```